# End-to-End Encryption & Syncing

Tags: security, encryption, synchronization, privacy

Our iOS app stores messages that users send each other in a PostgreSQL database on our server. Therefore, our users can access their entire message history on any device (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch) just by logging in.

We'd like to implement end-to-end encryption while still allowing our users to access their message history from any device.

Is this possible?

For example, if Apple's Messages app is end-to-end encrypted, then how is it able to sync across all of my devices?

Answer (score 3):

Of course: you can go two ways (well, at least two ways): let the users register their devices and list all the devices public keys. Then encrypt for all the devices using a single data key and encrypting using the various public keys. Disadvantage: adding a device means re-encrypting for the device.

You could also distribute a single private key encrypted by the password of a user to each device. Now the user has to enter a password to access the private key and the messages encrypted for it.

These are two ways of doing this; there will be more. I don't know how Apple does perform end-to-end encryption though.